# sending message to contacts in telethon python telegram

Tags: python, api, telegram, telethon

How can I see all my contacts and send them messages?
i use Telethon (API telegram python).

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ResolveUsernameRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputChannelEmpty
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.types.messages import Messages
from telethon.tl.types.contacts import Contacts
api_id = 1****
api_hash = '5fbd2d************************'
client = TelegramClient('arta0', api_id, api_hash)
client.connect()
```

Comment: Don't paste your api_hash and id here. It can be abused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this line to your code:

```
contacts = client.invoke(GetContactsRequest(""))
print(contacts)
```

And you should see the contacts in the result.

To send messages to contacts, you can use the `send_message` function defined in [telegram_client.py](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon/telegram_client.py) and has an example in [InteractiveTelegramClient.py](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/interactive_telegram_client.py).

```
for u in contacts.users: 
    client.send_message(InputPeerUser(u.id, u.access_hash), "hi")
```

If you need more details comment below and I will try to reply.

Comment: tanks (apadana i think you are persian and me to)  is work fore me..now how i can send message for my contact..

Comment: `client.send_message(InputPeerUser(u.id, u.access_hash), "hi")`  `NameError: name 'InputPeerUser' is not defined`

Comment: add this import: from telethon.tl.types.input_peer_user import InputPeerUser

Comment: please my bro can help me i want add Contact ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your last question. Are you asking how to add contact? If yes please post a new question and ping me.

Comment: i asking new question plz help me..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597384/add-new-contact-in-api-telegram-python-telethon

Comment: @netdevil Posted an answer

Comment: what hash value we need to provide in place of empty string GetContactsReques("")

Answer (score 1):

Sending empty string didn't worked for me:

```
contacts = client.invoke(GetContactsRequest(""))
*** struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

So I think you should use '0' instead:

```
contacts = client.invoke(GetContactsRequest(0))
print(contacts)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think in new update `client.invoke()` is not defined.
I used following code and it worked for me.

```
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import GetContactsRequest
contacts = client(GetContactsRequest(0))
```