# add contact with telethon in python

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

Recently I tried to add contact in telegram with telethon, according to this tutorial:
1) [Add new contact in api telegram python telethon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597384/add-new-contact-in-api-telegram-python-telethon)
 ,I used this codes:

```
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone='+989122725691', first_name="user",
                        last_name="test")
result = ImportContactsRequest(contacts=[contact])
print(result)
```

But I in my output I get this :

```
ImportContactsRequest(contacts=[InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone='+989122725691', first_name='user', last_name='test')])
```

I can'd find out what is my problem, but when I go to my telegram app, this contact isn't add.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should call ImportContactsRequest with your client Instance.
e.g.

```
import random
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=random.randint(0,9999), phone='+98912******', 
    first_name="user",
    last_name="test")
result = client(ImportContactsRequest(contacts=[contact]))
print(result.__dict__)
```

**Author note**

[Official applications use random numbers](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/8f82880b938e06b7a2a27685ef9301edb12b4648/Telegram/SourceFiles/boxes/add_contact_box.cpp#L224-L226), and [we have had issues with it in the past](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/search?q=InputPhoneContact&type=Issues).