# How to add contacts to telegram using telegram API?

Tags: python, telethon, telegram-api

I have been trying to use telethon to:

1. Scrape and gather the members and their ID from my group.
2. Add those members as contacts in telegram. (adding contacts without the phone number)

So far, I have been able to create the CSV file of the members of my group with telethon,
but I am currently stuck at how to add these accounts as contacts in telegram.

Does anybody have a solution or code for this?

Comment: [Telegram API](https://core.telegram.org/method/contacts.addContact)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [add contact with telethon in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53436883/add-contact-with-telethon-in-python)

Comment: This should be up . im also stuck in this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188603/im-making-a-code-that-adds-multiple-contact-in-my-telegram-by-username-listed-in

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use for my case. I read from json file. You can customize the code to make it read from csv. But the main point is how you add contacts

```py
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import AddContactRequest
import json

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
phone_number = ''

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash)


async def add_contacts_from_json():
    await client.connect()

    # Ensure you're authorized
    if not await client.is_user_authorized():
        await client.send_code_request(phone_number)
        await client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter the code: '))

    # Load member details from JSON file
    with open('group_members.json', 'r') as json_file:
        member_details_list = json.load(json_file)

    # Add each member as a contact without exposing phone number
    # Just for test purpose i am adding first 2 members of my group
    member_details_list = member_details_list[:2]
    for member_details in member_details_list:
        try:
            await client(AddContactRequest(
                id=member_details["id"],
                first_name=member_details.get("first_name", ""),
                last_name=member_details.get("last_name", ""),
                phone=member_details.get("phone", ""),
                add_phone_privacy_exception=True, # True -> they can't see your number, False -> they can see your number
            ))
            print(f"Contact added: {member_details['first_name']} {member_details['last_name']}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to add contact for {member_details['first_name']} {member_details['last_name']}: {e}")

    await client.disconnect()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import asyncio

    asyncio.run(add_contacts_from_json())
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems similar to what I encountered using [tdl](https://github.com/Bannerets/tdl).
As detailed in this [TDLib issue](https://github.com/tdlib/td/issues/578), after restarting the telegram client, you first have to call `getUser` on a contact for TDLib to load it from the database so you can work with that contact.

Comment: I want to add a new contact, it doesn't exist yet